# Arabic characters are too small to read

Tags: html, css, fonts, arabic

Text of the same font and size is readable in English and not readable in Arabic. It is to small to recognize symbols.

some text here - بعض النص هنا

How are these situations usually handled?

Comment: just add a css for Arabic language and set higher font number!

Answer (score 4):

As long as your language is set like this in your markup:

```
<html lang="ar">
```

You can use the pseudo class `:lang()` with the appropriate [HTML ISO Language Code](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp) on the element you want to target.

Take this example which will apply a `font-size` of `20px` to your HTML when the language is set to Arabic:

```
html:lang(ar) { 
    font-size: 20px;
}
```